# IOS Button on a TableView-Navigation bar not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, uinavigationbar

I am new to ios developing. I'm trying to put a back button on a `UINavigationBar` which I added to the top of a `TableViewController` and all I want to do is to dismiss the `viewcontroller` and go back to the previous one. the segue between the two `viewController` is modally and I had done the same thing on the other `ViewControllers` that are not `UITableView` and they work perfectly so I feel it is because of the `UINavigationBar` or the `UITableViewController`.

I really appreciate any help in advance.

Comment: Can you provide some code?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand your question, you are presenting a view modally and trying to go back using navigation. Thats not gonna happen. See this explanation

**Push Segue**

It adds a new VC to `navigationController`. if we have requirement to manage our views in heiraricall manner we should use it. it adds new view to navigation stack . Back button is displayed . on clicking back button it popped the VC from `navigationController`.

**Modal Segue**

A modal segue is just one VC presenting another VC modally. No navigation stack created. Don't display back button . You have to create as when needed cusotmly.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I guess I did not explain my question very well. I had created a button my self and in the code I was using:
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
to dissmiss the current viewcontroller. but I found the problem. The type of the button that I had created was not properly set up even though I had done it in the IB, it was sending an action instead of sending an event. sorry if i don't make sense, i'm super sleepy but i'll edit this comment later